# kubernetes cluster unreachable:error loading config file`/home/.kube/config:permission denied while use helm list command

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minikube

command: helm list
Error:Kubernetes cluster unreachable:error loading config file ~/.kube/config" permission denied
please help on this issue

Comment: Please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on your `~/.kube/config` file:

```
$ ls -hal ~/.kube/config
-rw------- 1 user user 1.4K Jan 12 12:59 /home/user/.kube/config
```

If the second character isn't `r`, it means you (and so Helm) doesn't have access to the configuration file in order to read it. Give yourself access to read it with:

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.kube/config
```

---

If you are using an Ubuntu snap (e.g. via `snap install helm3`), there's a different cause: snaps by default are not able to read hidden directories, like `~/.kube` (the dot at the start of the file means it's a hidden file). You can fix this by either moving your Kubernetes configuration to a different location without a leading dot, or by installing the snap in "classic confinement" that has less stringent data-access policies:

```
$ sudo apt remove helm3
$ sudo apt install helm
error: This revision of snap "helm" was published using classic confinement and thus may perform
       arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
       which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed, repeat the command including --classic.
$ sudo snap install helm --classic
helm 3.10.1 from Snapcrafters installed
```